# Need clarification on setTimeout function output

Tags: javascript

I have one doubt in java script.I opened https://stackoverflow.com and then open developer window(by press f12 or inspect) and went to console and then execute below code.

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log('hello..')},5000);
```

output:

> 8
>   hello..

once I click on enter first display 8 after 5 sec it displays hello.. text.
Now my question is what is that number here(8), it is changed for different, different domains.

Comment: `8` is timeoutID returned by [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method

Comment: Why it is different from domain  to domain? What it means?

Comment: It has nothing to do with domains, they are guaranteed  to be unique within  same object (a window or a worker). If  you again use  `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` 9 will be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the returned value of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) :

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
>   passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

That is the ID of the timeout you've just set and you can use it to cancel it.

For example:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(fn, delay);
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

If the `clearTimeout` function is called before the `delay`, the `fn` function will never be executed.

You can find more details about `setTimeout` [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)